# Text Replacement in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

In my MS-Word template, my client sends template with an error in the header section, as below,

VERMONT, ROBIN S.       Date:  10/21/2017
File No:  312335        DOB:  05/02/1967Claim#:   RE155B53452
DOI:   06/21/2017

The error being the ‘Claim#’ coming up right next to the DOB value, while it should come on the next line, as below:

VERMONT, ROBIN S.       Date:  10/21/2017
File No:  312335        DOB:  05/02/1967
Claim#:   RE155B53452       DOI:   06/21/2017

Also, this error comes up occasionally in some files and not all, so to solve it, I created a word macro, as below:

```
Sub ShiftClaimNumber2NextLine()

  Dim rngStory As Word.Range
  Dim lngJunk As Long
  'Fix the skipped blank Header/Footer problem as provided by Peter Hewett
  lngJunk = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.StoryType
  'Iterate through all story types in the current document
  For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    'Iterate through all linked stories
    Do
      With rngStory.Find
        .text = "Claim#:"
        .Replacement.text = "^pClaim#:"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      End With
      'Get next linked story (if any)
      Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
    Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
  Next

End Sub
```

And I run the above macro through a Group Macro, as below:

```
Sub ProcessAllDocumentsInFolder()

Dim file
Dim path As String

' Path to folder
path = "D:\Test\"
file = Dir(path & "*.doc")
Do While file <> ""
Documents.Open FileName:=path & file

' Call the macro to run on each file in the folder
Call ShiftClaimNumber2NextLine

' Saves the file
ActiveDocument.Save
ActiveDocument.Close

' set file to next in Dir
file = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

When I run the macro ProcessAllDocumentsInFolder(), for all files with such an error, it shifts the ‘Claim#’ to the next line.

However, the problem is, it also does so for files that do not have such a problem, thereby adding one enter line below the DOB, as below (as depicted by the yellow line):

[image]

What changes should I make to my macro ShiftClaimNumber2NextLine() , so that it does not make any change to files which ***DO NOT HAVE*** the ‘Claim#’ problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation best suited to regular expressions see below link for similar issue, refer vba solution

https://superuser.com/questions/846646/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-a-pattern-in-a-ms-word-document

```
Sub RegexReplace()

    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")    
    On Error Resume Next

    RegEx.Global = True
    RegEx.Pattern = "[0-9]Claim#:"
    ActiveDocument.Range = _ 
     RegEx.Replace(ActiveDocument.Range, "\rClaim#:")        

End Sub
```